# $.post works fine but $.ajax give an error: "There should be no direct access to this script!"

Tags: jquery, callback

I am working at an autosuggest/autocomplete script using jQuery library. As you type in ajax fetch the data through a php file from a database and offers suggestions to the user.

**Issue1:** 
Now as the $.post request works fine:

```
/*this works*/
$.post("autosuggest.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){ 
            $('#suggestions').fadeIn();
            $('#suggestionsList').html(data);
            });
```

the $.ajax alternative give me the following error: ***there should be no direct access to this script!***

Here is the code that outputs the error:

```
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "autosuggest.php",
                data: {data: ""+inputString+""},
                success: callback
            });
            function callback(data) {
                $('#suggestions').fadeIn();
                $('#suggestionsList').html(data);
            };
```

**Issue2:** 
There's another weird thing with $.post, the callback functions needs to be declare inside the parantheses:

```
//this works
$.post( url, params, function callback(data) {
$("div").html(data);
}
```

if I declare the callback function outside it won't work:

```
//this won't work
$.post( url, params, callback(data)); 
function callback(data)
{
$("div").html(data);
}
```

Comment: FYI: `{queryString: ""+inputString+""}` is pretty pointless. You can use `{queryString: inputString}`

Comment: Thanks Felix, very useful comment indeed, it is obvious data is undefined and the callback calls the php with an undefined value. But in $.ajax alternative does not work the same way?

Comment: @Tomalak, it makes no difference:). I am trying to figure out why $.ajax won't work.

Comment: I did not say it would make a difference. That's why it is pointless. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first point: The error might be due to you naming the parameter differently: `queryString` vs `data`. Apart from that, both calls are exactly the same and in fact, `$.post` internally uses `$.ajax` to make the call.

Regarding your second point: That is not weird, you are doing two different things. In the first, you are passing a function to `$.post`. In the second, you are *calling* `callback` and passing its *return value* to `$.post` (which is `undefined`). You'd have to do: `$.post( url, params, callback);`.

Comment: for the issue1 I don't think it works if I use the same name. data is a variable that is being displayed after php processing anyway.

Comment: The thing is that your `$.post` call will send the data as `queryString=foobar` and `$.ajax` as `data=foobar`. The PHP script probably expects `queryString` to be present and throws an error if it does not. Just try it with: `data: {queryString: inputString}`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't give an answer to **issue1**, maybe is the server application who is telling that message?

In **issue2**, do it like this (remove "data" from $.post definition):

```
//this won't work
$.post( url, params, callback ); 
function callback(data)
{
    $("div").html(data);
}
```

Comment: Very clever/simple solution indeed. I pass the callback with the params parameters and display it with data after when is returned